# A common function for all payment gateways?

Tags: magento-1.7, payment-methods

I want to add a new functionality to magento when a particular order is succeeded. I am wondering is there any common function where all the payment gateways reaches before destroying the order session information so I can pick the new order information like customer, credit card etc for the new functionality and then redirect to the success page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is such a point since every method behaves differently and can/should have different callback URLs. Maybe you can get the information you need on the success page using the event `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_success` and use

```
$orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->>getLastSuccessQuoteId();
```

to get the last order id, then load the order

```
Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
```

and get the info you need from there.

Comment: Done by creating a helper class of the newly created module for the extra functionality from the Mage_Checkout_OnepageController success action. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create an observer for event "checkout_onepage_controller_success_action".
This is in successAction in Mage_Checkout_OnepageController.